(Radial Topology) How to join object instances on the edges of the circular shape?
I want to create something resembling a gear, to do that I start with a plane that represents a shape of a single gear tooth, add array modifier then either Simple Deform or Curve modifier to create a circular gear-alike shape, then I add Solidify + Subdivision Surface to add volume and create a smooth look.
The problem though is that Catmull-Clark subdivision creates a small gap where array modifier ends meet on the circular shape.
I think an easy solution would be applying a hypothetical "Merge by Distance" modifier before subdivision that would collapse vertices on said gap. I can't think of any that can serve this role. For what it is worth, I am already using "merge" setting on the Array modifier but it is predictably won't work in a situation I'm describing.
How can I fix this?
The only approaches I can think of: (1) use geometry nodes and (2) hacks with boolean modifier where a gap would be covered by an object that would do merge operation.
Sample illustration to my question:


Maybe what you're looking for is the Weld modifier? Not sure about your modifiers order though, do you really need the first Subdivision Surface?

Oh, that's exactly what I need! Thank you very much! Please, add this as an answer so I could accept it.

What you're looking for is the Weld modifier. It acts exactly like a (non-destructive) Merge by Distance operation.
